# Vue transition mode on on-demand components not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a SPA which has multiple pages. The pages are components and are loaded on-demand using web pack's code splitting.

The pages are wrapped with `<transition mode="out-in">` tag, however, the sequential transitions do not work on initial component loads.

Here's a git repo that reproduces the error https://github.com/ByEmke/vue-transition-mode-issue.

[Edit]
I want to emphasize the question on *transition mode*. It is the transitioning mode that does not work. The 'out-in' should ease out the disappearing element and ease in the appearing one and this should happen in sequence, however, it happens in parallel (as in there was no transition mode set). It does not work on initial component loads (you can clearly see it in the Github's example when running), but it works fine when switching afterwards.

Here's a gif showing the issue http://recordit.co/mtiNGNUNCp

Comment: Does this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9gprz6m5/ show a working version?

Comment: Yes, but this is exactly the issue I am facing, it does not work when components are loaded on-demand

Comment: I think the issue is with your transition css, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now, I'm gonna stick with a monkey patch, wrapping my pages by a relative div and positioning the pages absolutely to top.

http://recordit.co/KXFrymElAR

P.S. If there was to be some content below the pages, this patch wouldn't work, as the parent is of height 0. It works for my use case, but would need some more hacking around when there's a need for content below the on-demand components.

Following the github example, this is how the template looks like now:

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <transition name="ease" mode="out-in" appear>
            <component :is="page"></component>
        </transition>
    </div>

    <button @click="first">First page</button>
    <button @click="second">Second page</button>
</div>
```

and styling:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    &.ease-enter-active, &.ease-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    }
    &.ease-enter, &.ease-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the `appear` directive on the transition node

```
<transition appear>
   <!-- ... -->
</transition>
```

from the docs [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render)

EDIT:
With more information I think it's the transition css in main.vue

```
<style lang="sass">
    h2 {
        &.ease-enter-active, &.ease-leave-active {
            transition: opacity 1s ease;
        }
        &.ease-enter, &.ease-leave-active {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Try this

```
<style lang="sass">
    .ease-enter-active, .ease-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 1s ease;
    }
    .ease-enter, .ease-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't help

Comment: EDIT - issue still remains, have a look into the gif on updated question, it shows what's happening. I want the sequential transitioning straight away, which is not happening on initially loaded components. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: I'm getting a 403 on that gif.

Comment: Ugh, stupid app, sorry about it, have a look into the updated url

Comment: I'll have to take a look when I get home and can download the github example. Unfortunately my phone can't do development like that.